# How to make a vertical radial-gradient

Tags: css

Currently I have markup for a dotted border line since `border` is pretty crappy when it comes to making actual `dotted` borders. my markup is the following

```css
.dotted-line {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side,#3E3E3E calc(100% - .5px),transparent 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 6px 2px;
  height: 9px;
  width:100%;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="dotted-line"></div>
```

However the problem I am having is I want to be able to make the same sort of border but vertical instead of horizontal. I have set `background-repeat: repeat-x;` but then I just get one solid line. Is it possible to do a vertical `radial-gradient`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I played around with your horizontal border and got this vertical dotted border. Take a look at `background-repeat: repeat-y;`, it's now vertical and the `background-size` has also changed.

I changed the `width` and `height` to get a decent amount of space to play in.

```css
.dotted-line {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side,#3E3E3E calc(100% - .5px),transparent 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: 2px 6px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 9px;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="dotted-line"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this ? You forgot to change the dimension. Sorry if that's not what you asked.

```css
    .dotted-line {
      background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side,#3E3E3E calc(100% - .5px),transparent 100%);
      background-repeat: repeat-y;
      background-size: 2px 6px;
      height: 100vh;
      width:10px;
      margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="dotted-line"></div>
```